# Laravel 5.4 How to get all relations if user is an admin

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.4, has-and-belongs-to-many

E.G. $user->relatedModel (without parentheses) returns the entire RelatedModel collection if the user is an admin or the typical filtered collection if they are not.

I am trying to alter a number of user relationships so that if the logged in user is an admin, then they can see all models in that relationship without having to write the same conditions every time I need to use it, and without creating all the relationships in the property_user table for every admin on every related model that I need this on.

There is an answer here which explains fairly clearly what I want to achieve
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34910225/1080341
which is exactly the idea I am looking for except that when I try this in Laravel 5.4 it throws an exception when the user is an admin.

```
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation
```

If the user is a standard user the relationship returns the appropriate filtered collection.

Here is the code example from that answer

```
public function properties()
    {
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
        return Property::query();
    } elseif ($this->isManager() || $this->isBroker()) {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property');
    }

    return null;
}
```

This is already a large site with many relationship calls already written so I do not wish to have to refactor all those code instances when I believe I can simply modify the relationship definition.

How can I return a relationship from this function that includes all models when the user is an admin, and keep it so the use of $user->properties around the site will not need to be modified?

```
[2018-06-02 12:58:23] local.ERROR: LogicException: Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation in /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php:403
Stack trace:
#0 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(386): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationshipFromMethod('sites')
#1 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php(316): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getRelationValue('sites')
#2 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(1279): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->getAttribute('sites')
#3 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/app/Http/Controllers/Backend/SiteController.php(29): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__get('sites')
#4 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SiteController->index(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#5 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#6 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(44): Illuminate\Routing\Controller->callAction('index', Array)
#7 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(203): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(App\Http\Controllers\Backend\SiteController), 'index')
#8 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(160): Illuminate\Routing\Route->runController()
#9 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(572): Illuminate\Routing\Route->run()
#10 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Router->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#11 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(41): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#12 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#13 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#14 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#15 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#16 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#17 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php(65): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#18 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#19 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#20 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php(49): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#21 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#22 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#23 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php(64): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#24 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#25 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#26 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php(37): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#27 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#28 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#29 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cookie/Middleware/EncryptCookies.php(59): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#30 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#31 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#32 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#33 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(574): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#34 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(533): Illuminate\Routing\Router->runRouteWithinStack(Object(Illuminate\Routing\Route), Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#35 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(511): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatchToRoute(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#36 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(176): Illuminate\Routing\Router->dispatch(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#37 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(30): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#38 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#39 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#40 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#41 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(30): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#42 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#43 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#44 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#45 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#46 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#47 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php(46): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#48 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(148): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Closure))
#49 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#50 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline->Illuminate\Routing\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#51 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))
#52 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))
#53 /home/vagrant/Leadgen/public/index.php(53): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate
```

Comment: What's the exception's trace? How do you use this "relation" in your code?

Comment: Just added the stacktrace to the question. (this is looking at the $user->sites relationship) And I may have updated the question since you read it with more details. The first paragraph should explain better how I want to call this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it isn't a real relationship, you can't access it as one. Use this:

```php
$sites = $user->sites()->get();
```

If you want to access it as a property and don't need the query object (e.g. to add other constraints), you can use an accessor:

```php
public function getPropertiesAttribute()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
        return Property::all();
    } elseif ($this->isManager() || $this->isBroker()) {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Property')->get();
    }

    return null;
}
```

A dirty hack:

```php
public function sites()
{
    if ($this->isAdmin()) {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Site', 'id')->orWhereRaw(1);
    }
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Site');
}
```

Comment: This is where I thought answers might take me and is an acceptable compromise, but before I go this way I want to check if  there was some trick to return a fake relationship. E.g return belongsToManyForAdmin(Property::class) so maybe by extending the base Model class. Any other hackery suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I added a dirty hack.

Comment: The hack works if I make it the same relationship type as the default, i.e. in your hack example I had to use: `return $this->belongsToMany('App\Site')->orWhereRaw(1);` otherwise it is checking for relationship IDs on tables where they don't exist and throws an error. With this edit I will accept this answer and perhaps you can update the hack for other peoples reference. Thanks

Comment: I chose the `HasMany` relationship on purpose, but you are right about the foreign key column. The `BelongsToMany` relationship doesn't always work. Because of the JOIN, it only returns sites that have a pivot entry for any user. In your database, that's probably the case for all sites and so it looks it's working. I updated my answer.