# Laravel Eloquent can you do something similar to hasAll?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship, roles

Trying to return all Locations for a User if the user is admin, otherwise use the hasManyThrough function.  Curious if this is possible?

```
public function locations()
{
    if ($this->hasRole('Admin')) {
      //return all locations
      return $this->has(Location::all());
    } else {

      return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Location::class,
        UserLocations::class,
        'user_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'location_id'
      );
}
```

}

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50656606/laravel-5-4-how-to-get-all-relations-if-user-is-an-admin

Comment: so you want to return a HasManyThrough associated to all the locations? no you can't, how Eloquent should be able than to structure the queries? If you really what, you can return `Location::query()`, but will return a Builder

Comment: And checkout the mutator documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: I do like it dirty, thanks man!